# Positive Jacobian implies preserving local homology groups

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to figure out why it is true that two definitions of orientability, one using local homology groups and one using tangent vectors are equivalent. This boils down to the following statement:

If $f$ is a diffeomorphism from open $0\in V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ to open $0\in V'\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f(0)=0$, then the induced map $f_\ast:H_n(V,V-0)\rightarrow H_n(V',V'-0)$ is the identity map iff the Jacobian of $f$ at $0$ is positive, where we identify $H_n(V,V-0)$ and $H_n(V',V'-0)$ to $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-0)$ via excision.

I'm stuck on why this is true, can someone help me see this? Thank you!